# How to use valueBinding for toggle radio buttons?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have posted my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/2Ys5j/2/).
Here i have used radio button to define gender.

```
        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Gender</label>
        <div class="controls">
                <p><div id="gendertype" name="gender" class="btn-group rdgender" data-toggle="buttons-radio">                    
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Male</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Female</button>
              </div></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to implement binding in such way that it should support existing implementation of CRUD functionality.

But i am not able to implement binding for radio button in this scenario(refer provided fiddle).
Can anyone tell me how to implement  binding  for toggle radio buttons in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create view for you radio buttons and use class binding to toggle `active` class on specific button depending on `gender` property

UPD:
also you can just bind class on some boolean property:

```
<button type="button" {{bindAttr class=":btn :btn-info controller.currentContact.male:active"}}>Male</button>
<button type="button" {{bindAttr class=":btn :btn-info controller.currentContact.male::active"}}>Female</button>


App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    gender: DS.attr('string'),
    contacttype: DS.attr('number'),
    male: function(){
        return this.get('gender') == 'Male';
    }.property('gender')
});
```

Comment: :Can you explain me this with example?